# How to send stdin to IPython?

Tags: python, ipython, stdin

I'm having trouble trying to send data through stdin to IPython, it seems that EOF is interpreted as an exit command for ipython ?

Example:

`echo '"hello"' |ipython`

```
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: Out[1]: 'hello'

In [2]: Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)?
```

And the process quits without me doing anything else.

Is there a parameter to set or something ?

---

Edit: To make the context clearer, the real scenario where I want to do this is the following:

`program1 | ipython -i -c "%run script"`

program1 would output something (a json), and ipython would run a script that load the thing into something I can use, then leave me to a IPython interpreter where I can play with it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: There is a fundamental flaw with what you are trying to do. When you pipe something into something else, it doesn't add it to an otherwise untouched file descriptor; it replaces the file descriptor of `stdin`, meaning that you won't be able to type then because IPython won't even read `stdin` anymore.

Comment: Just use regular Python rather than IPython.

Comment: @BlackBeans : Interesting, then I guess I'll have to do this another way. I've updated the question to make the objective behind it clearer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell : It has the same problem in this context (see answer below), and it's not a solution even if it worked. I use IPython *specifically* because I don't want to use Python as an interactive tool.

Answer (score 1):

Same as comment. your question is quite unclear.

Maybe pipe some python command to a python interperter?

try this

```
$ (echo 'a=123' && cat ) | ipython -i
Python 3.6.9 (default, Mar 15 2022, 13:55:28)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.16.3 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]:
In [2]: print(a)
123
```

this will execute `a=123` and make python into interative mode which take your keyboard input

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but your commands gives the same behaviour (i.e. python will close immediatly).

Comment: 1) See my comment about why using pipes like that will not work 2) `$(echo "a=123" | cat)`... this is clearly flawed bash that is both redundant (because piping to `cat` like that is useless) and dangerous, because it will actually try to execute (as a bash command) `a=123` and pipe that into python...

Comment: @Pythalex i've made a typo here sorry. it's been fixed and tested in my environment

Comment: @BlackBeans  i've made a typo here and yes,  gree about pipe's wrong here. hard to explain but i've check cpython's code, that seems in interactive mode python will use sys.stdin,sys.stdout,sys.stderr. kinda straghtforward, or else keyboard input func like input() won't work at all

Comment: Actually using `cat` is smart, but it's not related to ipython's interactive mode (in fact you can even get rid of the `-i` and it will still work), that because you are reading from the actual `stdin` and piping it into ipython's `stdin`.

Comment: @BlackBeans thank you for this comment which helps me clarify pipes, fd, and something  like hierarchy. but tried not using `-i`, ipython works as expected but plain python not. seems still worth to  looking into...

Comment: @KevinChan my bet is that it's because Python will detect it's input source is not a terminal, but a "file". If you try doing so with `ptpython`, for instance (which is an alternative python repl, like ipython) it will say "Warning: Input is not a terminal", and die like Python.